# Django - print all objects attribute values

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, django-context

**HTML**

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    {% for field in fields %}
    <th>{{ field }}</th>
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  {% for well in well_info %}
  <tr>
    <td><p>{{ well.api }}</p></td>
    <td><p>{{ well.well_name }}</p></td>
    <td><p>{{ well.status }}</p></td>
    <td><p>{{ well.phase }}</p></td>
    <td><p>{{ well.region }}</p></td>
    <td><p>{{ well.start_date }}</p></td>
    <td><p>{{ well.last_updates }}</p></td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
  <tr>
```

**views.py**

```
class WellList_ListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'well_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'well_info'
    model = models.WellInfo

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['fields'] = [field.name for field in models.WellInfo._meta.get_fields()]
        return context
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse


# Create your models here.
class WellInfo(models.Model):
    api = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    well_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phase = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    region = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    start_date = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_updates = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.well_name
```

I was able to list all attribute field names by getting context['fields'], but I don't know how to automatically print each objects all attributes values.

So in my html file, I hard-coded all the attribute names, but I want to know if I can to this in a more elegant way, by using for loop. So something like:

```
<tbody>
  {% for well in well_info %}
  <tr>
    {% for value in attribute_list %}
    <td><p>{{ well.value }}</p></td>
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
  <tr>
```

Comment: `[attr+': '+str(getattr(object,attr,'fail')) for attr in vars(object)]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `getattr`, you could construct a list of list of values, like:

```
fields = context['fields']
context['well_info'] = [
    [getattr(o, field) for field in fields ]
    for instance in context['well_info']
]
```

If you write `getattr(x, 'y')` this is equivalent to `x.y` (note that for `getattr(..)` we use `'y'` as a *string*, so it enables us to generate strings and query for arbitrary attributes).

For every instance in the *old* `well_info`, we thus replace it with a sublist that contains for every field, the relevant data.

Note that here the `well_info` attribute is no longer an iterable of model instances, but a list of lists. If you want to access both, it might be better to store it under another key in the context.

You can then render it like:

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    {% for field in fields %}
    <th>{{ field }}</th>
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  {% for well in well_info %}
  <tr>
    {% for value in well %}
    <td>{{ value }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
  <tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: can you show how your version of code will be implemented in html?

Comment: Your code works. But if I were to stick ur method over other methods, is it necessary that I pre-define context['fields'] before?

Comment: @EricKim: no, you can simply perform the list comprehension, and thus work directly on that list.

Answer (score 2):

In your context include:

`context['wellinfo'] = [(field.name, field.value_to_string(self)) for field in Well_Info._meta.fields]`

Then you can loop through it in the template like:

```
{% for name, value in wellinfo.get_fields %}
{{ name }} {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```