# Print all attributes from an object with Django templates

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, attributes

I am a novice programmer, I am learning python and Django on my own. I got stuck in a part of my application:

I have many models with many attributes, and I have a window and a template for each of them.
The idea is to show in each one, a table with all its content with an sql query in the file view.py

`objects.all ()`

My code:

**MODELS.PY**

```
from django.db import models

class MFuel(models.Model):
    marca = models.TextField(db_column='Marca', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    modelo = models.TextField(db_column='Modelo', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    potencia_electrica_kw = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='Potencia_electrica_kW', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    fecha_oferta = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Fecha_oferta', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    pais_proyecto = models.TextField(db_column='Pais_Proyecto', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    proyecto = models.TextField(db_column='Proyecto', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    uds = models.FloatField(db_column='Uds', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    precio_eur = models.FloatField(db_column='Precio_EUR', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    precio_usd = models.FloatField(db_column='Precio_USD', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    precio_unitario_eur = models.FloatField(db_column='Precio_Unitario_EUR', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    ratio_eur_kw = models.FloatField(db_column='Ratio_eur_KW', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    largo_mm = models.FloatField(db_column='Largo_mm', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    ancho_mm = models.FloatField(db_column='Ancho_mm', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    alto_mm = models.FloatField(db_column='Alto_mm', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    peso_kg = models.FloatField(db_column='Peso_kg', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    presupuesto = models.TextField(db_column='Presupuesto', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    esp_tecnicas = models.TextField(db_column='Esp_Tecnicas', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    observaciones = models.FloatField(db_column='OBSERVACIONES', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'm_fuel'
```

**VIEWS.PY**

```
def m_fuel(request):
    fuel = MFuel.objects.all()

    # QuerySet
    myFilter = Filter(request.GET, queryset=fuel)
    fuel = myFilter.qs

    total = fuel.count()

    attr = MFuel.__doc__

    inici = attr.index("(") + 1
    fi = attr.index(")")
    nom_columnes = attr[inici:fi]
    nom_columnes = str(nom_columnes)
    nom_columnes = nom_columnes.split(",")

    dict = {
        "fuel": fuel,
        "filter": myFilter,
        "motores": motores_list,
        "total": total,
        "nom_columnes": nom_columnes,
    }

    return render(request, "motores/fuel.html", dict)
```

**TEMPLATE.HTML**

```
<table class="table_info">
        <tr>
            {% for nom in nom_columnes %}
            <th>{{nom}}</th>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>

        {% for i in fuel %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{i.id}}</td>
            <td>{{i.marca}}</td>
            <td>{{i.modelo}}</td>
            <td>{{i.potencia_electrica_kw}}</td>
            <td>{{i.fecha_oferta}}</td>
            <td>{{i.pais_proyecto}}</td>
            <td>{{i.proyecto}}</td>
            <td>{{i.uds}}</td>
            <td>{{i.precio_eur}}</td>
            <td>{{i.largo_mm}}</td>
            <td>{{i.ancho_mm}}</td>
            <td>{{i.alto_mm}}</td>
            <td>{{i.peso_kg}}</td>
            <td>{{i.presupuesto}}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

My idea is to automate the table columns by accessing all the attributes of the class.
I tried pulling out a list of the attribute names

```
attr = MFuel .__ doc__
```

and print them as follows:

```
<table class="table_info">
        <tr>
            {% for nom in nom_columnes %}
            <th>{{nom}}</th>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>

        {% for i in fuel %}
        <tr>
            {% for nom in nom_columnes %}
            <td>{{i.nom}}</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

but this shows nothing:
[capture that this code shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eemD7.png)

It seems that it does not recognize the name as an attribute of the class, it must be because it is a string?

I saw this question, but I don't understand it
[Django - print all objects attribute values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51430386/django-print-all-objects-attribute-values)

**Any help to automate this? Thanks a lot**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been able to solve my problem, I share it in case someone needs it

This returns a list of all the values available:

```
fuel = fuel.values()
```

and print them:

```
<table class="table_info">
    <tr>
        {% for nom in nom_columnes %}
        <th>{{nom}}</th>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% for i in fuel %}
    <tr>
        {% for key, value in i.items %}
            <td>{{value}}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

And all ok